# Interact with Active/Single IE11 Session VBA

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

So I have a loop that exports data from a website. However, for each case, it starts a new session and closes. Is there a method to navigate and download for all the cases in just **one** IE11 session and then closing out? Below is the code that I have right now:

```
Public Sub Get_File()

    Dim sFiletype As String     'Fund type reference
    Dim sFilename As String     'File name (fund type + date of download), if "" then default
    Dim sFolder As String       'Folder name (fund type), if "" then default
    Dim bReplace As Boolean     'To replace the existing file or not
    Dim sURL As String          'The URL to the location to extract information
    Dim Cell, Rng As Range
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet

    'Initialize variables
    Set Rng = Range("I2:I15")
    Set Sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Macro_Button")

    For Each Cell In Rng
        If Cell <> "" Then
        sFiletype = Cell.Value
        sFilename = sFiletype & "_" & Format(Date, "mmddyyyy")
        sFolder = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cell.Value, Sheet.Range("I2:J15"), 2, False)
        bReplace = True
        sURL = "www.preqin.com"

        'Download using the desired approach, XMLHTTP / IE
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cell.Value, Sheet.Range("I2:W15"), 15, False) = 1 Then
            Call Download_Use_IE(sURL, sFilename, sFolder, bReplace)
            Else
            Call Download_NoLogin_Use_IE(sURL, sFilename, sFolder, bReplace)
            End If

        Else
        Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Download_Use_IE(ByRef sURL As String, _
                            Optional ByRef sFilename As String = "", _
                            Optional ByRef sFolder As String = "", _
                            Optional ByRef bReplace As Boolean = True)

    Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
    Dim hDoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim objInputs As Object
    Dim ele As Object

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    'Create IE object
    Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
    oBrowser.Visible = True

    'Navigate to URL
    Call oBrowser.navigate(sURL)
    While oBrowser.Busy Or oBrowser.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

    'Skips log in step if already signed into website
    On Error GoTo LoggedIn

    'Enter username
    oBrowser.document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_cphSiteHeader_ucLoginForm_user_email").Value = "XXX"
    oBrowser.document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_cphSiteHeader_ucLoginForm_user_password").Value = "XXX"

    'Submit the sign in
    oBrowser.document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_cphSiteHeader_ucLoginForm_btnLogin").Click
    'Wait for website to load
    While oBrowser.Busy Or oBrowser.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

LoggedIn:

'All PE
    oBrowser.navigate Range("H3").Value
    'Wait for website to load
    While oBrowser.Busy Or oBrowser.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
    'Set the htmldocument
    Set hDoc = oBrowser.document

    'Loop and click the download file button
    Set objInputs = oBrowser.document.getElementsbyTagName("input")
    For Each ele In objInputs
        If ele.Title Like "Download Data to Excel" Then
            ele.Click
        End If
    Next

    'Wait for dialogue box to load
    While oBrowser.Busy Or oBrowser.readyState > 3: DoEvents: Wend
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

    'IE 9+ requires to confirm save
    Call Download(oBrowser, sFilename, sFolder, bReplace)

    'Close IE
    oBrowser.Quit

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    'Resume
    Debug.Print "Sub Download_Use_IE() " & Err & ": " & Error(Err)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your download_IE procedure to use a Browser that is passed to it:

```
Private Sub Download_Use_IE(oBrowser As InternetExplorer, _
                           ByRef sURL As String, _
                        Optional ByRef sFilename As String = "", _
                        Optional ByRef sFolder As String = "", _
                        Optional ByRef bReplace As Boolean = True)

    Dim hDoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim objInputs As Object
    Dim ele As Object

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    'Create IE object

    oBrowser.Visible = True

    'Navigate to URL

    Call oBrowser.navigate(sURL)

    ......rest of code

    Call Download(oBrowser, sFilename, sFolder, bReplace)

    'Do not Close IE

 Exit Sub

 ErrorHandler:
     'Resume
     Debug.Print "Sub Download_Use_IE() " & Err & ": " & Error(Err)
 End Sub
```

Then modify your procedure to pass this object:

```
Public Sub Get_File()

    'declare all variables plus:

     Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer

     Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer

     .....put additional code here.....

     If Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cell.Value, Sheet.Range("I2:W15"), 15, False) = 1 Then
         Call Download_Use_IE(oBrowser, sURL, sFilename, sFolder, bReplace)
        Else
        Call Download_NoLogin_Use_IE(oBrowser, sURL, sFilename, sFolder, bReplace)
        End If
      Else
         Exit Sub
      End If
    Next

     'Close IE
     oBrowser.Quit

 End Sub
```

You will need to do the same thing for the other procedure.

Comment: Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/users/4560433/opiesdad! Works perfectly. The only slight issue is that the IE doesn't close anymore for some reason. Any idea what might be causing that line to not execute?

Comment: My fault, I didn't analyze your code too closely.  Your line "Else Exit Sub" is causing the procedure to be exited before reaching the "oBrowser.Quit" line.  Change the line to "Else GoTo Exit_Sub", then put a label "Exit_Sub:" immediately before the "oBrowser.Quit" line.